# Emphasize the current year instead of removing the current year and only tooltipping it

Tags: feature-request, search, dates

I am not happy with the "hover" for year solution.

1. For example, search for "pex". Most hits are old. How do I find/subset the recent ones? I cannot search for 2012 because 2012 is not in the string.
2. It's just non-intuitive because one has to just "know" that the code behind is computing and presenting omitting the year. Not all sites do this!

It's a bit better for me now that I know so better, but I would prefer that to highlight that 'this post is current' that emphasis be added rather than data removed.

Thus, I advocate having bold or italic or underline on dates that are current. That would be even easier.

See also; the post;
Add year to question and answer dates so can search in search.

Comment: It's much more noticeable because new posts don't have the year info, so their posts times are shorter. Adding emphasis would attract attention constantly which is unwarranted.

Comment: Like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2012-12-31)?

Answer (score 2):

The search page has a "newest" tab that orders the result from the most recent post to the older post.

[image: screenshot]

If you only want to get the most recent posts, you don't need to add the year in all the timestamps. As the dates are normally relative, such as "2 days ago," I don't think that writing that as "2 days ago, 2012" would be something very useful, and using an absolute date such as "February 8, 2012" probably wouldn't be something I would like to see.